# Why * (asterisk) immediately go to the next occurrence in vim?

Tags: vim

Let's see a simple example:

```
Some text TOM, some text
           ^ (my cursor here)
Some TOM, some text
```

After pressing `*` I get:

```
Some text TOM, some text
Some TOM, some text
     ^ (now cursor here)
```

It always jump to the next word and it's annoying. I just want it to stay at the same place including `TOM` to the search pattern (for the next occurrence pressing `n`). It's useful when I want to refactor variable name starting from the cursor.

For example if * simply include a word to search pattern I could do the following:

```
tom := "some text"
 ^ (cursor)
func test() {
  println(tom)
}
```

`*`(add old name to pattern) `ciw`(change a word) `newname`(write new one) `n`(next occurrence) `.`(repeat last command). Is there any option to change behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need `` (2 backticks, Gary Bernhardt calls it "tick-tick-back") to jump back:

```
*``ciwfoo<Esc>n.n.
```

Note that you can use `cgn` instead of `ciw` and skip the `n` step:

```
*``cgnfoo<Esc>..
```

And remap it if you don't like to press "tick-tick-back":

```
nnoremap <key>       *``cgn
nnoremap <other-key> #``cgN
```

Comment: It seems that the first time I used * command the behaviour was different (the same I was expected). Am I wrong?

Comment: I guess in this link you can find the solution: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov, `*` always moves the cursor to the next occurence of the word under the cursor. There is no reason whatsoever to expect a different behavior… unless you have a mapping somewhere that changes the default behavior.